# Understanding pseudocode for beginner

Tags: python, list, pseudocode

Is pseudocode really as simple as it sounds? Or am I completely missing something? I need to write pseudocode for a simple program to display months of the year including the number of month. Will this work??

```
Create list containing months
Use for statement to create loop
Display month number w/ name
```

Reading various sources and currently attending an online class that provides very little feedback when needed.

Comment: I think that you shouldn't bother with pseudocode, just go straight to python.

Comment: Pseudocode in general is a language-agnostic way to describe an algorithm by describing the statements you'd use when implementing the algorithm in a specific language. Since many programming language are very similar, pseudocode tends to look a lot like some of them, especially when people with a specific programming-language background write it. What you've written is less pseudo-code and more a description of the algorithm. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Pseudocode_implementation for an example

Comment: "Use for statement to create loop" doesn't sound like pseudocode so much as a description of actual code. Describe what the loop is supposed to do, not how you will implement it. That said, I agree that pseudocode is not particularly helpful here. Python itself is sometimes describes as being executable pseudocode (exaggerated of course, but with an element of truth).

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode is useful for thinking about your approach to a problem without language specific syntax. It's quite an individual thing and lots of people would skip it altogether.

I think what you have is pretty good for that but I would probably write it:

```
months_list = [list containing each month]

for month in months_list

print month and index of month
```

This reads pretty closely to actual python code because python is quite human readable.
From this you would then implement and tackle the specifics.

Answer (score 1):

There's some fuzziness, but in general pseudocode is more explicit than what you have, without quite the rigor of actual code. If I were to phrase what you have as pseudocode, I would write:

```
myList = ["Jan", "Feb", ...]
for i = 0 to 11:
    print(i + ":" + myList[i])
```

That won't compile in any language, but it is created out of language-like constructs that anyone could more-or-less unambiguously translate into whatever language they're familiar with.

(Usually you would not write pseudo-code for something that simple, but it's useful when you're describing an algorithm which is complex enough that you don't want to burden the reader with the specifics of syntax.)

Comment: I would say you've made this too code-like for a non-coder to understand.  I think @MDavidson has the same functionality, but closer to what I'd consider pseudo code.  Yours is Python with a syntax error.